# How are global-menus intergrated with Firefox?

Tags: unity, firefox, globalmenu

How is the global menu added to Firefox? The nightly releases are great but obviously lack Canonical's intergrations. I have tried the Unity Customisations plugin for Firefox that comes with the default Firefox installation but that's clearly not it as it makes no difference to menus on either browser.

Global menu and HUD are the only thing preventing me taking advantage of the huge performance increase in 57 so I'd really appreciate any insight as to how to complete the intergration.

[image: Image showing Firefox Nightly with missing global menu]